# What is the minimal amount of RAM to built an 3.11.0 x86_64 kernel on 13.10 with 8 cores?

Tags: 13.10, kernel, compiling

I have configured a KVM virtual machine (VM) with 8 processor cores and 256 MB of RAM and no swap. A minimal text based Ubuntu Saucy 13.10 amd64 was done. The essential packages to build/recompile the 3.11.0 kernel were installed.

- The intended architecture for building the kernel is ARCH=x86_64.
- The running kernel is amd64 3.11.0-18-generic.
- Gcc is version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9).

When executing the command:

```
fakeroot make-kpkg -j 8 --initrd --append-to-version=-custom kernel_image kernel_headers"
```

It finally ends with:

```
make: *** [debian/stamp/build/kernel] Error 2
```

The first error in the console output is:

```
  CC      drivers/gpio/gpio-stmpe.o
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:2242: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
{standard input}:4413: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.l'
{standard input}: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing .cfi_endproc directive
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make[3]: *** [net/ipv6/udp.o] Error 4
make[2]: *** [net/ipv6] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

My first idea is that the amount of random access memory (RAM) is confired to low (256MB).

#### Update #1

After having a look at the console, I am sure that the build machine has too little RAM:

```
Out of memory: Kill process 8128 (cc1) score 117 or sacrifice child
Killed process 8128 (cc1) total-vm:102432kB, anon-rss:23184kB, file-rss:0kB
```

#### Update #2

Increasing to 384MB, 512 or even 640MB of RAM is not enough to stop "Out of memory" error messages.

What is the **minimum** amount of **RAM required** to **build the kernel**?

Comment: Why don't you just increase it until it is enough?  1 GB is the practical minimum amount of ram these days for doing just about anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**768MB** of RAM was enough to compile the 3.11.0 kernel where ARCH=x86_64.

Note that 640MB was not enough.

*In this case the .config file was modified to localmodconfig and later on some options were disabled and others enabled. The resulting .config file size is 86458 bytes.*